# Strange behavior of double data type

Tags: java, integer, double

My code is as follows:

```
Number inputAmount = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(Locale.FRANCE).parse("7,10");
double doubleValue = inputAmount.doubleValue();
int intValue = (int) (doubleValue * 100);

System.out.println("Input: " + inputAmount);
System.out.println("Double: " + doubleValue);
System.out.println("Integer: " + intValue);
```

which outputs:

```
Input: 7.1
Double: 7.1
Integer: 710
```

But, when the `inputValue` is 5,10 the output is:

```
Input: 5.1
Double: 5.1
Integer: 509
```

This happens only with 5,10 and 4,10. I know that it happens due to the double precision but I cannot figure out exactly how. 
Any ideas?

Comment: Looks like 4 and 5 cannot be exactly represented like 7 can be..

Comment: Yes, I used BigDecimal after I encountered this problem, and that fixed it, but I wanted to know why first method didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is, that the multiplication `5.1d * 100d` produces a rounding error, that results in `509.99999999999994d`. And when you cast this double into an integer, then the result is obviously `509`.

To understand what is going on here, consider the following:

```
double doubleValue = 5.1d * 100d; // rounding error...
System.out.println("Double: " + doubleValue);
int intValue = (int) doubleValue;
System.out.println("Integer: " + intValue);
```

Output:

```
Double: 509.99999999999994
Integer: 509
```

Comment: It is strange though that it only happens with 5.10 and 4.10 value.

Answer (score 0):

try changing:

```
int intValue = (int) (doubleValue * 100);
```

to:

```
int intValue = (int) (doubleValue * 100d);
```

Your code is fairly simplified already, I'm thinking something weird might be going on with the internal casting when it multiplies. 100d will force it to multiply two doubles before final conversion to int.